# button cannot activate onclick function from javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I was trying to call web service with ASP.NET AJAX. But I encountered the following error.
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.index_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'onClick' and no extension method 'onClick' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.index_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Anyone know how to fix this?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services><asp:ServiceReference Path="~/CountryCodeFinder.asmx" /></Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function onClick() {
            Task3.CountryCodeFinder.CodeFinder(form1.tbxInput.value, onSuccess, onFailed);
        }
        var onSuccess = function (result) {
            $get("lblResult").innerHTML = result;
        }
        var onFailed = function (result) {
            $get("lblResult").innerHTML = " Not Found! ";
        }

    </script>

    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Find Country Code" onclick="onClick()" />
        <br />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The onclick of a ASP.NET button looks for a method in the code behind (that is run on the server), in your case named 'onClick', which it can't find and this is why you get that compile error.

You probably want to use the onClientClick to run javascript (msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx)

If you're not going to do anything with the button on the server side, you might want to replace it with a simple html input tag:

```
<input type='button' onclick='onClick()' value='Find country code'></input>
```